# Control Meteor Mongo Query Batch Size

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm setting up simple pub/sub on a mongo collection in a meteor application.

```js
// On Server
Meteor.publish('records', function (params) {

  if (params.gender === "Male") {
    params.gender = "M";
  } else if (params.gender === "Female") {
    params.gender = "F";
  }

  return Records.find({
    gender: params.gender || {$exists: true},
    age: {
      $lte: params.ageRange.max,
      $gte: params.ageRange.min
    }
  });
});

//On Client
    this.computationBlock = Tracker.autorun( () => {
      Meteor.subscribe("records",
                       _.pick(this, ["gender","ageRange"]));
      RecordActions.recordsChange(Records.find({}).fetch());
    });
```

These queries occasionally return 10,000+ (total) documents, and the issue is that it returns about 300-500 documents per batch. I have visualizations of aggregated metrics from the query, and so these visualizations often remain in flux for over 10 seconds as each new batch of the query result is brought down from the subscription/publication. I'm pretty sure that if I could configure the batchSize property of the mongo cursor returned from Collection.find(), I could alleviate the problem simply by returning more documents per batch, but I cannot find how to do this in meteor land.

cursor.batchSize is undefined in both the client and server code, although it is simple part of mongo native api (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/). Has anyone had any luck configuring this parameter, or even better, telling meteor to fetch the entire query in "one-shot" as opposed to batching the results?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've patched this by resorting to a meteor method whose return value is Cursor.fetch() instead of a reactive pub/sub model. The drawback is that now the client won't be notified of collection updates until next time it calls the method, but the performance tradeoffs were well worth it.

Comment: use the limit option?

Comment: Sorry Mark, the issue was that I actually need all of the documents to generate the correct aggregate visualuzations, so limiting the number of records returned would not work in this case.

Comment: so do the computation on the server side and return the result to the client

Comment: that's what i mentioned as my temporary solution above. the issue is that now it's not reactive in the sense that the meteor method would be automatically re-fired when the collection changes on the backend, but for now it's fine.